# Log viewer cant open syslog after messing up groups

Tags: permissions, administration, sudo, syslog

I was doing some VirtualBox stuff today and I had so add my user to vbox group, well I did it wrong and I removed myself from sudoers. I used the recovery console and fixed it with this command:

```
usermod -a -G admin MyUser
```

Now I can sudo again, but I went to the graphical log viewer (because ubuntu is booting kinda slower now and I wanted to see if I can find something there), and I see that it can't access syslog and other files from there because it says I don't have permissions. Previously I was able to see all the log files from "System Log Viewer", without having to use sudo or anything, just launching it as my normal user.

**What could be happening?**

btw, I know I can access syslog from any text editor with sudo, but I want to find why I was able to access it from the GUI before without sudo and now I can't. I am using ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 2):

Members of the `adm` group can read logfiles. Not only did you remove yourself from the `admin` group, you also removed all other groups.

To add yourself back to the `adm` group again:

```
sudo gpasswd -a MyUser admin
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, now the remaining errors are a lot of "no such file or dir" on log files like, jockey.log, user.log, boot, debug, btmp, messages, etc. Should I do something about that ?

Comment: `/var/log/messages` has been vanished a year ago iirc. You can ignore those warnings.